# Back to Top Button in footer

Tags: html, css

i Have a Question About How To Create a Scroll Back To Top Button fixed in footer ?
like this one

[Link](https://www.graphicsprings.com/)

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqIua.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jquery to it

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#header").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Html

```
<div id="button">Click me </div>
<div id ="header">...</div>
```

Here is plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/LVi19SUIgi55qbhKzpaV?p=preview

Comment: can you give the full code

Comment: @Hax_dz I editet my answers . Check this

Comment: Thnx !  Problem sloved :D

Answer (score 1):

You simply add an a tag and href= to the ID you wish to jump to. For example:
Higher in your code you have, say right under your body tag, `<div id="top"></div>`
the further down on your page, in multiple places if you so chose, ad a tags that reference that lD in the link; `<a href="#top"></a>`. When you click on that href `a` tag, it push the top of the view port/screen to that div.

Basic HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">  
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div id="container>
    <div class="header">Welcome</div>
    <p>......whole bunch of content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"><a href="#top">Back to the top</a>
</div>
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thnx This was helpful

Comment: @Hax_dz Glad I could help. If you are satisfied with the answer do not forget to mark your answer as solved. 

 BTW, here is a jsfiddle, though all you need is simple html to achieve this. 

https://jsfiddle.net/j7jo80jm/